# Using mutate in R to rename items in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

*EDIT*

I am trying to name a column and rename all items within the column of a dataset:

```
dataSet <- read.csv(url) %>%

rename("newColumn1" = V1) %>%

mutate(newColumn1 = recode(newColumn1, "oldEntryX" = "newEntryX") %>%

select(dataSet, newColumn1)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in recode(newColumn1, oldEntryX = "newEntryX" : 
object 'newColumn1' not found
```

What am I missing?

The code runs correctly up through the rename function and displays the renamed column correctly, but soon as I include mutate it throws an error.

I have no problem sharing the real code but wanted to generalize it for the crowd.

source info was from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data

Comment: If you can provide subset of data or the url it is even better for us to help you. In your question, you have to `"` that shoul not be there before `nexColumn`. is this a typo or the source of your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

IN the `mutate` step, you don't need quotes for column names on the `lhs` of `=`.  Also, there are couple of case mismatches

Assuming the dataset is read correctly, we can

```
df1 %>% 
   rename(newColumn1 = V1, newColumn2 = V2)  %>%
   mutate(newColumn1 = recode(newColumn1, oldEntryX = "newEntryX"), 
           newColumn2 = recode(newColumn2, oldEntryY = "newEntryY"))
```

---

Based on the OP's code there is no closing quote as well `"newColumn1`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = sample(c("oldEntryX", "x", "y"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
 V2 =  sample(c("oldEntryY", "x", "y"), 10, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with some simple codes of R programming:
**How to read csv file**
**Syntax** :-  `read.csv("filename.csv")
by using this command 1st row will be used as header. To improve this fault one should write

```
data <- read.csv("datafile.csv", header=FALSE)
```

**How to rename the header/Column name:**

```
names(data) <- c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```

Now your headers are replaced by Column1, Column2 and Column3

**Now to change Column1 data you can follow steps**

```
data$Column1 <- c(write down set of values with which you want to replace)
```

**To see the output type**

```
data
```